# Magento: How to move top links into nav block?

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I am trying to figure out how to move the top links (My Account, Login, Checkout, etc) into the nav block that contains the list of category names. I'm using Magento 1.4.2. Here is a screenshot to show what i mean:

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4043/11404620.jpg

At the moment i believe the top links are in the links block. I'd like to achieve this by adding some xml to local.xml so that i can upgrade more easily in the future. So far i've only been able to remove the top.links with this:

```
 <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.links" />
```

but i have no idea how to add them to the nav block. Hopefully once i know how to do this i will understand Magento better, the layout aspect of it has me confused. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The nav block is generated directly from the categories. You can recreate the layout XML within the nav block itself, but you will need to modify the nav PHTML itself to include the toplinks after generating the catalog categories.

Keep in mind that this is generally a poor information hierarchy, which is why it is structured this way in the first place.